# Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class

Tags: cocoapods

I am facing an issue with Podfile as below while installing pod in Xcode project.

> Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class

I did try to update pod version with `brew upgrade cocoapods` and also followed below link:

https://dev.to/retyui/fix-a-pod-install-error-undefined-method-exist-for-fileclass-react-native-24ke

But still no fix.

Please guide me what am I doing wrong here.

Below is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'


flutter_application_path = '../bmi_flutter'
    
load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')

target 'MixedNativeApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)
  # Pods for MixedNativeApp

  target 'MixedNativeAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MixedNativeAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is my solution for above problem (Posting if it could be helpful for devs in same situation)

```
gem cleanup
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0 -n /usr/local/bin   ***`add cocoapod version u want to install`***
sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: This work like a charm on Mac M1. Thanks for solution

Comment: When i sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0 -n /usr/local/bin   ,
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::BadURIError)
    both URI are relative

How can i fix it ?

Comment: I did all Gagan_iOS said in the comment. At first it didnot work. Then i cleaned my project with "npx react-native-clean-project".  Then run yarn install (and postscript made pod install then i saw an error  that one lib needs 1.12.0 cocoapods version). After that I made everything from the Gagan_iOS  comment and installed 1.12.0 version of cocoapods, cleaned the project, and run yarn install. On this time pod install work. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Downgrade cocoapods version can fix it. But if you use XCode 14.3++ and want to archive app, you will get issues.

I tried this way and it worked, open this file in your flutter sdk:

```
flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/pod_helper.rb
```

Then replace

```
return [] unless File.exists? file_path
```

to

```
return [] unless File.exist? file_path
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Never would have figured that out. The error message points to the project level podfile and that already was `exist`.

Comment: Thank you, but what did this change fix exactly? This is part of the flutter itself, not the project.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the suggested solutions but none of them seemed to work. However, after some more digging, I found a piece of code that could potentially fix the problem. I replaced the problematic code with the following in the pod file:

```
if !File.exists? file_abs_path
```

--to--

```
if !File.exist? file_abs_path
```

(exist instead of exist**s**)

After making this change, the error no longer appeared and the program ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

1. brew remove cocoapods
2. Same problem on 2.8.0 stable with cocoapods 1.11.3. To resolve this switch cocoapods to 1.11.2 sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.2. Remember to remove 1.11.3 version first.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue to build old Flutter project.

```
Flutter SDK 2.10.4
My cocoapods version 1.14.1
```

I solved issue by updating gem

```
sudo gem update
```

updated cocodpods and all files related with cocoapods