# How to can I run Flutter App on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

My flutter SDK is as below:
Flutter 2.8.1
Dart 2.15.1

My chip is Apple M1 Pro; My flutter app can successfully run in Android simulator.
But when I try to run my flutter app on iOS simulator, I get this error:
CocoaPods' output:
↳
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class. #  from /Users/jenny/Documents/test_flutter/parkinsons_behavior_app_Chinese/ios_parkinsons_update/ios/Podfile:34 #  ------------------------------------------- # >    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)) #  end #  ------------------------------------------- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:335:in` rescue in block in from_ruby'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:329:in `block in from_ruby' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in` instance_eval'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:327:in` new'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:327:in `from_ruby' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in` from_file'

How can I solve this problem and let it successfully run on iOS.

Comment: There is a similar problem. Try this solution : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696725/13922303)